# does local storage clear values automatically if browser in idle mode for some time duration?

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

does local storage clear values automatically if browser in idle mode for some time duration? as i am working on one of web application in php where lots of data is in localstorage for quick movement of data. 
Now at one point, my screen stands in idle mode around 1hour and than as i am going to do any other action, screen throws script error suddenly.

can anyone give some idea on this ?

Answer (score 0):

It should not delete by itself unless you tell it so. 
But the local storage is tied to the site that you are accessing just like the sessions would do. Is there any chance that the idle time causing the site to navigate to any other URL which doesn't have what you stored before ( just guessing)..!

Comment: No. it's just idle mode for one hour +. so when i am going to execute any other event operation it freeze the screen and i got to know about script error. that localstorage variable is undefined. 
now i am refreshing my page and everything is working fine.